# CBLAS installation issue: undefined reference to `_gfortran_store_exe_path'

Tags: gcc, gfortran, cblas

I downloaded CBLAS (cblas.tgz) from http://www.netlib.org/blas/ and tried to install CBLAS and has the following error:

```
[kokep@n007 CBLAS]$ CC=gcc-8.1 LDFLAGS="-L/home/kokep/bin/lib" CFLAGS="-I/home/kokep/bin/include" make

( cd src && make all)
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/projects/kokep/kokep/devel/libraries/CBLAS/src'
ar cr  ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a cblas_srotg.o cblas_srotmg.o cblas_srot.o cblas_srotm.o cblas                                                                                    _sswap.o cblas_sscal.o  cblas_scopy.o cblas_saxpy.o cblas_sdot.o  cblas_sdsdot.o cblas_sn                                                                                    rm2.o cblas_sasum.o cblas_isamax.o   sdotsub.o   sdsdotsub.o snrm2sub.o sasumsub.o isamax                                                                                    sub.o  cblas_drotg.o cblas_drotmg.o cblas_drot.o cblas_drotm.o cblas_dswap.o cblas_dscal.                                                                                    o  cblas_dcopy.o cblas_daxpy.o cblas_ddot.o  cblas_dsdot.o cblas_dnrm2.o cblas_dasum.o cb                                                                                    las_idamax.o   ddotsub.o   dsdotsub.o       dnrm2sub.o dasumsub.o idamaxsub.o cblas_cswap                                                                                    .o cblas_cscal.o cblas_csscal.o cblas_ccopy.o cblas_caxpy.o cblas_cdotu_sub.o cblas_cdotc                                                                                    _sub.o cblas_icamax.o cdotcsub.o cdotusub.o icamaxsub.o  cblas_zswap.o cblas_zscal.o cbla                                                                                    s_zdscal.o cblas_zcopy.o cblas_zaxpy.o cblas_zdotu_sub.o cblas_zdotc_sub.o cblas_dznrm2.o                                                                                     cblas_dzasum.o cblas_izamax.o zdotcsub.o zdotusub.o dzasumsub.o  dznrm2sub.o  izamaxsub.                                                                                    o  cblas_scasum.o scasumsub.o cblas_scnrm2.o scnrm2sub.o cblas_sgemv.o cblas_sgbmv.o cbla                                                                                    s_sger.o cblas_ssbmv.o  cblas_sspmv.o cblas_sspr.o  cblas_sspr2.o cblas_ssymv.o cblas_ssy                                                                                    r.o  cblas_ssyr2.o cblas_stbmv.o cblas_stbsv.o cblas_stpmv.o cblas_stpsv.o  cblas_strmv.o                                                                                     cblas_strsv.o   cblas_dgemv.o cblas_dgbmv.o cblas_dger.o cblas_dsbmv.o  cblas_dspmv.o cb                                                                                    las_dspr.o  cblas_dspr2.o cblas_dsymv.o cblas_dsyr.o  cblas_dsyr2.o cblas_dtbmv.o cblas_d                                                                                    tbsv.o cblas_dtpmv.o cblas_dtpsv.o  cblas_dtrmv.o cblas_dtrsv.o   cblas_cgemv.o cblas_cgb                                                                                    mv.o cblas_chemv.o cblas_chbmv.o cblas_chpmv.o cblas_ctrmv.o cblas_ctbmv.o cblas_ctpmv.o                                                                                     cblas_ctrsv.o cblas_ctbsv.o cblas_ctpsv.o cblas_cgeru.o cblas_cgerc.o cblas_cher.o  cblas                                                                                    _cher2.o cblas_chpr.o  cblas_chpr2.o  cblas_zgemv.o cblas_zgbmv.o cblas_zhemv.o cblas_zhb                                                                                    mv.o cblas_zhpmv.o cblas_ztrmv.o cblas_ztbmv.o cblas_ztpmv.o cblas_ztrsv.o cblas_ztbsv.o                                                                                     cblas_ztpsv.o cblas_zgeru.o cblas_zgerc.o cblas_zher.o  cblas_zher2.o cblas_zhpr.o  cblas                                                                                    _zhpr2.o  cblas_sgemm.o cblas_ssymm.o cblas_ssyrk.o cblas_ssyr2k.o cblas_strmm.o cblas_st                                                                                    rsm.o cblas_dgemm.o cblas_dsymm.o cblas_dsyrk.o cblas_dsyr2k.o cblas_dtrmm.o cblas_dtrsm.                                                                                    o   cblas_cgemm.o cblas_csymm.o cblas_chemm.o cblas_cherk.o cblas_cher2k.o cblas_ctrmm.o                                                                                     cblas_ctrsm.o  cblas_csyrk.o cblas_csyr2k.o cblas_zgemm.o cblas_zsymm.o cblas_zhemm.o cbl                                                                                    as_zherk.o cblas_zher2k.o cblas_ztrmm.o cblas_ztrsm.o  cblas_zsyrk.o cblas_zsyr2k.o cblas                                                                                    _globals.o cblas_xerbla.o xerbla.o
ranlib ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/projects/kokep/kokep/devel/libraries/CBLAS/src'
( cd testing && make all )
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/projects/kokep/kokep/devel/libraries/CBLAS/testing'
gfortran  -o xscblat1 c_sblat1.o c_sblas1.o ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a /mnt/projects/kokep/koke                                                                                    p/devel/libraries/BLAS-3.8.0/blas_LINUX.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o): In function `main':
(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `_gfortran_store_exe_path'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [xscblat1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/projects/kokep/kokep/devel/libraries/CBLAS/testing'
make: *** [alltst] Error 2
```

I have two questions here. First, I would like to use my own version of GCC libraries but it directs to the default root gcc library.

Second, Is the default libgfortranbegin.a outdated? If yes, how and where can I get it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post here. Libfortranbegin.a is not used in modern GCC, do not try to find it, remove it from your makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to define the fortran compiler FC and use the full C compiler path for CC variable, as an example:

> CC=/usr/bin/gcc-8.1 FC=/usr/bin/gfortran-8.1  make

You can find the CC path compiler with the following command:

> which gcc-8.1